# (ngx-bootstrap) Close a modal that has been created with a component programmatically

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I have an Angular 5 application using ngx-bootstrap.
I create two modals using the [Modal Component](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-component). I need to close the first modal after some time and then open the second modal.

I tried both of these before opening the second modal but...

- ...when I use `this.modalService.hide(0)` in the component I show the modals in, nothing happens
- ...when I use `this.modalService.hide(1)` in the component I show the modals in, the second modal opens and closes right after

Also `this.modalReference.hide()` didn't do it.

Any suggestions highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get your scenario working with the following implementation

In app.component.html

```
<div bsModal #modalone="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal ONe</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div bsModal #modaltwo="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Two</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button (click)="toggle()">Toggle</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above modal sections note two important things; 1) Each modal section has a reference to the modal directive via `bsModal` 2) there's a reference to the element node using #... Also it is imperative that reference has different names... In this example, i've opted to use `#modalone` and `#modaltwo`. Each reference here is passed an instance of `ModalDirective`.

In app.component.ts obtain a reference of the modal elements using the `@ViewChild()` decorator with the reference name used above. (see full docs here https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

```
 @ViewChild('modalone') public modalone: ModalDirective;
 @ViewChild('modaltwo') public modaltwo: ModalDirective;

 // Required to toggle
 one: boolean = true;
```

In your `ngAfterViewInit()` life cycle hook toggle the first modal using the `show()` function. The initial show() call is performed within the AfterViewInit lifecycle hook in order to have the element's node at hand. This will enable the first modal.

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.modalone.show();
}
```

Add a simple toggle function (that is referenced in the modal html above) to switch between the two modals.

```
toggle() {
    if (this.one) {
        this.modalone.hide();
        this.modaltwo.show();
    } else {
        this.modalone.show();
        this.modaltwo.hide();
    }

    this.one = !this.one;
}
```

This should demonstrate the toggling between two modals as you require... Here's a working plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/F5oWAI?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! This didn't work for my particular problem because the ModalComponent doesn't use the ModalDirective but the answer is very good nonetheless.

For anyone wondering what my solution was: I has to use setTimeout since the ModalService.show and the onShown event of the ModalService return before the modal is shown.